# How to return a list of csv files contained in a folder as a list and be able to set a variable from the list

Tags: windows, batch-file, indexing, cmd

I'm trying to figure out how I can return a list of csv files contained in a directory and then be able to set a variable from the list.

for example if "D:\folder1" contains 3 csv files I'm trying to figure out how to display them as a list us such:

1: csv1
2: csv2
3: csv3

I then want to be able to use the above list as variables so for example -

"please select the index number above for the file you wish to open:"

where I can enter an index number above and get a result like the below -

```
if %index" = 1 set csvname="csv1"
if %index" = 2 set csvname="csv2"
if %index" = 3 set csvname="csv3"
```

"insert command to open D:\folder1%csvname%.csv

any help will be greatly appreciated. I know how to use choice and IF "%ERRORLEVEL" equ "1" for example but i dont know how to combine that with a command to display files as an index number and then use the index number as the choices.

Hopefully that makes sense to someone.

Thank you

update:

If i use the below script it successfully returns a list of all csv files however it behaves as if i have chosen to exit and doesn't let me actually choose.

```
echo off

set /a count=0

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem loop over file and set env1=to first filename; env2=second filename 
etc.
for %%i in  (D:\Folder1\*.csv) do (
set /a count+=1
echo !count!. %%~ni
set env!count!=%%i
set choices=!choices!!count!
)

set choices=%choices%x
echo X. Exit

echo.
choice /C %choices% /N /M "Selection:"

set myFile=!env%ERRORLEVEL%!

endlocal && set myFile=%myFile%

rem if "" then X picked so exit 
if "%myFile%" equ "" goto exit

rem echo filename
echo %myFile%

:exit
```

Comment: the error i get from running the above is:

ERROR: Duplicate choices are not allowed.

Comment: Your `%choices%` variable is predefined by accident (probably from earlier testing). Delete the variable with `set "choices="`

Comment: I'd move the `setlocal` directly after the `echo off` and delete the `endlocal` line completely, then run the batch in a brand-new `cmd` instance. This would prevent the variables from a former run being carried over to subsequent runs.